# jQuery don't affect to app part

Tags: app

I'm create a Web Part like this.
Open VS 2013 -> New Project -> App for SP -> SP hosted app.
Then I add Client Web Part and named it AppPart and I've made some changes in Elements.xml .

```
<Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/AppPart.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;BGColor=_BGColor_" />
<Properties>
  <Property Name="BGColor"
            DefaultValue="R"
            WebCategory="Custom Settings"
            Type="enum"
            WebDisplayName="Background Color"
            RequiresDesignerPermission="true">
    <EnumItems>
      <EnumItem Value="R" WebDisplayName="Red"/>
      <EnumItem Value="B" WebDisplayName="Blue"/>
      <EnumItem Value="G" WebDisplayName="Green"/>
    </EnumItems>
  </Property>
</Properties>
```

Inside AppPart.aspx I made some changes:

```
<script src="../Scripts/AppPart.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="width:200px;height:200px">
    <h2>Hello from AppPart</h2>
</div>
```

And I'm also have AppPart.js file like this:

```
var sProp = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("BGColor"));
changeBGColor(sProp);
document.write('Value of BGColor : ' + sProp + '</br>');
function changeBGColor(color) {
switch (color) {
    case 'R':
        $("#content").css("background", "Red");
        break;
    case 'B':
        $("#content").css("background", "Blue");
        break;
    case 'G':
        $("#content").css("background", "Green");
        break;
    default:
        $("#content").css("background", "red");
        break;
}
```

}

And then I deployed it. Go to my site -> Page -> Edit -> Insert -> App Part -> Select my apppart. BUT, problem is, the background of div content doesn't change, even when I'm hard code like this in my AppPart.js it still don't effect or even when I use console of chrome and type like this, I got error (Cannot read property 'css' of null).

```
$("#content").css("background","red");
```

So, what am I missing, I don't know why jQuery don't effect to my AppPart.

Comment: make sure your stuff shoud be into $(document).ready(function(){ // add your stuff });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App part (from a SharePoint app) is rendered as an `iframe` when placed on a page.

Hence the scripts that are loaded on the page where you place it will not be added to the `iframe`. An `iframe` is a completely separate `document` with its own DOM.

So you would have to load in jQuery also in your app part, by using a `<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH TO jQuery"></script>` style of tag in the app part itself.